# How vector iterator's copy-constructor use SFINAE to allow for iterator to const_iterator conversion?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, sfinae

While studying various `std::vector`'s iterator implementations, I noticed this copy-constructor which uses SFINAE to allow initializing constant iterators from non-constant ones and vice versa:

```cpp
// Allow iterator to const_iterator conversion
// ...
      // N.B. _Container::pointer is not actually in container requirements,
      // but is present in std::vector and std::basic_string.
      template<typename _Iter>
        __normal_iterator(const __normal_iterator<_Iter,
              typename __enable_if<
           (std::__are_same<_Iter, typename _Container::pointer>::__value),
              _Container>::__type>& __i) : _M_current(__i.base()) { }
```

It's a common knowledge that the iterators for *vectors* are defined this way:

```
      typedef __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<pointer, vector> iterator;
      typedef __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const_pointer, vector>
      const_iterator;
```

I can't understand how the checking of container's `pointer` type against `Iter` allows the conversion. If I pass a constant iterator, `Iter` should be `const_pointer`, won't that fail the `enable_if<>` check and discard this constructor from the set? Which one will be used then?

Could you please explain how this constructor works and maybe bring an example of such substitution?

P.S.
Another question is why `std::list` doesn't use the same technique of avoiding code duplication by declaring iterators like this. It has two separate classes for both versions of iterators. I wonder if it's possible to implement list's iterators in the very same way as vector's

Comment: *"If I pass a constant iterator, `Iter` should be `const_pointer`"* You don't. This is a constructor, not a conversion operator, so you pass a non-const iterator to the constructor of const iterator.

Comment: i still don't understand why plain definition of `normal_iterator(const normal_iterator &i) : _M_current(__i.base()) { }` doesn't do the trick and how SFINAE makes a difference with its enabling, and why the same doesn't work for `std::list` iterators

Comment: I don't know about list iterators, but what you proposing would be just a copy constructor, while you asked about a conversion from a non-const to a const iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I pass a constant iterator, Iter should be const_pointer, won't that fail the enable_if<> check and discard this constructor from the set? Which one will be used then?

Yes, that's exactly what happens, because that definition would be an ambiguous overload of the default (implicit) copy constructor. These extra constructors are there to allow the *implicit* conversion to happen only from non-const to const iterator, and explicit conversion from pointer-like types to iterators.

As for `std::list`, I don't know! It could simply be an arbitrary implementation detail, or maybe this way was considered to be more readable/maintainable.

Comment: thank you for your answer. what if I copy-construct `const_iterator` from another `const_iterator`? won't that also fail the check?

Comment: @Mampac Yes, and it would choose the implicitly defined `__normal_iterator(const __normal_iterator&)` constructor, with the `_Iterator` parameter being the `const_pointer` type.